# Nested IF / AND statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I think I've made a mistake as it keeps returning `#VALUE`.

```
IF(AND(G2="green",G3="green"),"GG"), IF(AND(G2="red",G3="red"),"RR"),
IF(AND(G2="red",G3="green"),"RG"), IF(AND(G2="green",G3="red"),"GR")
```

I'm trying to say if it is red and it is green, print RG and others such as RR,GR,GG.

Comment: Why not `=upper(left(g2)&left(g3))` ?

Answer (score 2):

The `IF()` function takes three arguments: `Test`,`Then-value`,`Otherwise-value`. So the function should look like this:

```
=IF(AND(G2="green",G3="green"),
    "GG",IF(AND(G2="red",G3="red"),
            "RR",IF(AND(G2="red",G3="green"),
                    "RG",IF(AND(G2="green",G3="red"),
                            "GR"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it as,

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(G2:G3,{"red","green"}))=2,UPPER(LEFT(G2)&LEFT(G3)), TEXT(,))
```

Comment: On the worksheet the `LEFT(<string>, <length>)` function defaults to a single character if no length parameter is provided; in VBA the length parameter for `Left(<string>, <length>)` is required.

Comment: the upper left version you first posted is so short, succinct and elegant - you should post it as an answer - gets my vote.

Comment: I wasn't sure if there where other options. The above incorporates the core of it while guaranteeing that there are two red/green values in the cells. The OP should be able to figure out something from the two of them.